# How to implement multiple languages in one page with Ngx Translate

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, ngx-translate

I'm using Angular 9 and I'm trying to use different translations on the same page. For example, I have an angular library that i want to translate in Spanish and my main angular app in English. but when I try to do so, it keeps with the library translation language. It doesn't differentiate my translations/languages from library own translations/languages.

I tried this on my library:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslateDefaultParser, TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";

@Injectable()
export class MyTranslateService extends TranslateService {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(
            null,
            new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json"),
            null,
            new TranslateDefaultParser(),
            null,
            false,
            true,
            false,
            null
        );
    }
}
```

```js
import { TranslatePipe, TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { MyTranslateService} from "../services/myTranslate.service";

// tslint:disable-next-line: use-pipe-transform-interface
@Pipe({
    name: "myTranslate",
    pure: false,
})
export class MyTranslatePipe extends TranslatePipe {
    constructor(@Inject("customTranslator") private customTranslator: MyTranslateService, private detectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        super(customTranslator, detectorRef);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,
    MyTranslatePipe 
  ],
  providers: [
    MyTranslateService,
    { provide: 'customTranslator', useExisting: MyTranslateService}
  ]
})
...
```

With this I tried {{ 'translationkey' | myTranslate}} in my components on library but gives me this error:

```
home.component.html:67 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of null
    at MyTranslateService.getParsedResult (ngx-translate-core.js:878)
    at MyTranslateService.get (ngx-translate-core.js:905)
    at MyTranslateService.updateValue (ngx-translate-core.js:1475)
    at MyTranslatePipe .transform (ngx-translate-core.js:1516)
    at Object.updateRenderer (home.component.html:71)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:47482)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:46461)
    at callViewAction (core.js:46821)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:46778)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:46456)
```

Can anyone help me with this question, please?
Thanks.